# Is it possible to go rootViewController page from any page?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am trying to build an iPhone app. I am trying to build it at View based application.

Suppose I have gone to y.xib file from x.xib nib file. and x.xib nib file has been come from  root.xib file. I would like to go root.xib file from y.xib.

How?

Answer (score 7):

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

Comment: Terminate at UINavigationController* navView=topView.navigationController;

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the popToRootViewControllerAnimated method on the UINavigationController.

Answer (score 0):

in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

_initalStoryboard = self.window.rootViewController.storyboard;

```
- (void)resetWindowToInitialView
{
    for (UIView* view in self.window.subviews)
    {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }

    UIViewController* initialScene = [_initalStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = initialScene;
}
```